# How to automatically call script with environment variable set

Tags: bash, git, jenkins, code-reuse

I want to be able to call this script using `./script.sh -e "${env}" -a "${app}"`. -e (environment), while -a (application). Basically, by setting the environment as either stage or prod it grabs the IP addresses automatically. Note: I am using Jenkins for this and pulling the code from GIT. The goal is not to hardcode IPs in the script to enable re-use of the code.

Any ideas ?

```
#!/bin/bash

while [[ $# > 1 ]]
do
OPTIONS="$1"

case $OPTIONS in
    -a|--application)
    APPLICATION="$2"
    shift # past argument
    ;;
    -s|--ip)
    HOSTS_STAGE="$2"
    shift # past argument
    ;;
    -p|--ip)
    HOSTS_PROD="$2"
    shift # past argument
    ;;
    --default)
    DEFAULT=YES
    ;;
    *)
            # unknown option
    ;;
esac
shift # past argument or value
done

echo "########################################"
echo "##  OS Updates on ${APPLICATION}  ##"
echo "########################################"


if [[ "${ENVIRONMENT}" == 'stage' ]]; then
IPS="${HOSTS_STAGE}"

elif [[ "${ENVIRONMENT}" == 'prod' ]]; then
IPS="${HOSTS_PROD}"

fi


echo "---------------------------------------"
echo "##  Performing update in ${ENVIRONMENT}"
echo "---------------------------------------"

for ip in $IPS; do

    echo "---------------------------------------"
    echo "##  Running yum update on ${ip}"
    echo "---------------------------------------"

    ssh -i "${id_rsa}" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no dvopsadmin@${ip} "df -h"
    done

   if [[ ${REBOOT} == y ]]; then
   for ip in $IPS; do
       echo "---------------------------------------"
       echo "## Rebooting server on ${ip}"
       echo "---------------------------------------"

       ssh -i "${id_rsa}" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no dvopsadmin@${ip} "uname -a"
       done
   else
      echo "------------------------------------------"
      echo "##  Updates alredy performed withot reboot"
      echo "------------------------------------------"

   fi
```

Comment: What processes the `-e` option? I was going to suggest just setting the variables directly: `APPLICATION="$app" ENVIRONMENT="$env" ./script.sh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you use [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin).  You can use this plugin to set env variables at the top of your Git project.. checkout the link for instructions.  You can create two env variables, e.g. APP & ENV.

Then in you "Execute shell" section you can use the env variables.

```
./script.sh -e "${ENV}" -a "${APP}"
```

EDIT:

```
if [ "${ENVIRONMENT}" == 'stage' ]; then 
    IP="${IP_S[@]}" 
elif [ "${ENVIRONMENT}" == 'prod' ]; then 
    IP="${IP_P}" 
fi 

for host in ${IP}; do 

    echo "---------------------------------------" 
    echo "## Running yum update on ${host}" 
    echo "---------------------------------------" 


    if [ "${REBOOT}" == 'y' ]; then 
        ssh -i "${id_rsa}" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no dvopsadmin@${host} "uname -a; df -h" 
    elif [ "${REBOOT}" == 'n' ]; then 
        ssh -i "${id_rsa}" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@${host} "uname -a" 
    fi 
done
```

Comment: It is kinda set up like this now. Only difference is, I have to call it using `./script.sh -s ${HOST_STAGE} -a ${APP}` and `./script.sh -p ${HOST_PROD} -a ${APP}`. (host_stage/prod is basically a parameter for stage IPs)

Comment: Were do you want to put the env and IP?

Comment: I want to put it next to `./script.sh `

Comment: Where are you putting it now that is causing a problem?

Comment: I put it in a Jenkins parameter called HOST_STAGE and HOST_PROD with the IP values. The script works fine. I just wanted to find a more efficient way of doing it

Comment: I see.  More efficient would be somewhere global so that it does not need to be set per project?

Comment: in my Jenkins job. I also had to add an if/elif statement to check for both env. I took this out of the code `if [[ "${ENVIRONMENT}" == 'stage' ]]; then
IPS="${HOSTS_STAGE}"`

`elif [[ "${ENVIRONMENT}" == 'prod' ]]; then
IPS="${HOSTS_PROD}"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170157/discussion-between-bonafideaf-and-jose-martinez).